# What is 720p video recording

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-nexus-s

I heard about the complaint of the Nexus S' lack of 720p video recording? What does 720p mean? How does it compare to the standard Samsung Galaxy S phones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/720p):

> 720p is the shorthand name for a
>   category of HDTV video modes having a
>   resolution of 1280×720 (for a total of
>   0.92 megapixels or 921,600 pixels) and a progressive scan. The number 720
>   stands for the 720 horizontal scan
>   lines of display resolution (also
>   known as 720 pixels of vertical
>   resolution), while the letter p stands
>   for progressive scan or
>   non-interlaced. When broadcast at
>   60 frames per second, 720p
>   features the highest temporal (motion)
>   resolution possible under the ATSC and
>   DVB standards.

The Samsung Galaxy S [is capable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S) of recording 720p video from it's rear-facing camera.  The Nexus S [is not](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9661355&postcount=3) (max resolution of 720x480).

Comment: Beat me to the Wikipedia entry :)

Comment: @Daniel - Questions like this really are a quick-draw competition. lol

Comment: true :)

Answer (score 5):

Its referring to the resolution that the video camera can record video in. [720p](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/720p) (1280×720 ) is a High Definition resolution.  Apparently the maximum video resolution of the Nexus S is only 720x480 which is Standard Definition.  Many new Android handsets have the ability to record HD video which is why it would be something to complain about with the Nexus S.